# Cannot correctly setup React-Router-Dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4

Hi I'm currently working with `react-router-dom`. I seem to have not followed the instructions properly because I'm having this issues:

```
bundle.js:1085 Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `history` is marked as required in `Router`, but its value is `undefined`.
  in Router

bundle.js:2279 Uncaught Error: A <Router> may have only one child element
    at invariant (bundle.js:2279)
    at Router.componentWillMount (bundle.js:47987)
    at bundle.js:35732
    at measureLifeCyclePerf (bundle.js:35459)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (bundle.js:35731)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (bundle.js:35642)
    at Object.mountComponent (bundle.js:41991)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (bundle.js:35755)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (bundle.js:35642)
    at Object.mountComponent (bundle.js:41991)
```

And these are the parts of the application where I do use `react-router-dom`:

routes.js:

```
"use strict";
const React = require('react');
const Switch = require('react-router-dom').Switch;
const Route = require('react-router-dom').Route;
const Router = require('react-router-dom').Router;
const Home = require('./components/homepage');
const AuthorPage = require('./components/authors/authorPage');
const About = require('./components/about/aboutpage');

const Routes = (
    <Router>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route path="/authors" component={AuthorPage} />
            <Route path="/about" component={About} />
        </Switch>
    </Router>
);

module.exports = Routes;
```

main.js:

```
"use strict";
const React = require('react');
const ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
const BrowserRouter = require('react-router-dom').BrowserRouter;
const App = require('./components/app');

ReactDOM.render(<BrowserRouter> <App /> </BrowserRouter>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

app.js:

```
$ = jQuery = require('jquery');
const React = require('react');
const Header = require('./common/header');
const Routes = require('../routes');

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Header />
                <Routes />
            </div>  
        );
    }
}

module.exports = App;
```

**Update 1:**

I removed the `<Router> </Router>` wrapping in **routes.js** and the first error is gone. Thanks to: @Keith Alpichi

Answer (score 1):

First, the [`Router` requires a `history` object](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Router). Import `createBrowserHistory` then create it.

```
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'

const history = createBrowserHistory()

<Router history={history}>
  <App/>
</Router>
```

However, you have to decide if you're going to use `BrowserRouter` or plain `Router` because based on the documentation only `Router` requires the `history` object. If you decide to use the former remove `Router` from your `Routes` variable you declared in `routes.js`. If you decide to use `Router` change `BrowserRouter` in `main.js` to `Router`.

Second, since you're already defining a [`Router`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Router) component in `main.js` you don't need another one in `routes.js`. So remove the outer `Router` tag like so:

```
const Routes = (
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
    <Route path="/authors" component={AuthorPage} />
    <Route path="/about" component={About} />
  </Switch>
);
```

Comment: So I should leave only the `<Switch>`?